# Simple questions about synchronizer

Tags: flipflop, synchronization

1) For table 1 of [Berkeley paper](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs150/sp10/Collections/Papers/ClockCrossing.pdf#page=2) , why "Input must be valid for at least two clock periods in the new domain." ?

The explanation:

> the width of the input pulse must be greater than the period of the synchronizer clock plus the required hold time of the first synchronizer flip-flop. The safest pulse width is twice the synchronizer clock period.

Could anyone tell why it has to do with **hold time of the first synchronizer** flip-flop ?

2) For pulse synchronizer or what we known as toggle synchronizer, I do not understand the explanation highlighted in yellow that is given below:

> One restriction of a pulse synchronizer is that input pulses must have a minimum spacing between pulses equal to two synchronizer clock periods.
>
> This problem is more severe when the clock period of input pulse is greater than twice the synchronizer clock period

[image: pulse synchronizer]

Answer (score 1):

The input signal needs to be stable in order to avoid issues with meta stability. Consider the timing diagram taken from [this article](https://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1276114):
[image: meta stability]
C1 and A are in your source clock domain and C2 and B are in your destination clock domain. If the clock edges violate the timing constraints, the B flip-flop may not detect the high A input. If A changes before the next C2 edge, the high A signal will be missed. This is why you need to hold A stable for two clock periods.

Comment: Why is it hold time but not the setup time of the first synchronizer flip-flop ?

Comment: @kevin it is both really. This is why I said timing constraints.

Comment: you do not really need hold time in this case since the signal A is "before" the rising clock edge of C2.  Even if it is "after" the rising clock edge of C2, we will regard it as being missed by that particular rising edge of C2

Comment: @kevin you have to keep in mind that the diagram shows one possibility. If your C2 clock occurs just before the A signal changes, you’ll have a hold time violation.

Comment: So, it is both setup time and hold time. But why is setup time ignored ?

Comment: @kevin the paper you have linked to mentions both setup and hold timing constraints.

Comment: ok, I saw it.

> "A long enough glitch that occurs at the correct time could meet the setup-and-hold requirements of the first flip-flop in the synchronizer, leading the synchronizer to pass a false-valid indication to the rest of the logic in the new clock domain."

Comment: However, the article explanation for question 1 above ignored setup time. What did I miss ?

Comment: @kevin Worst case scenario for a setup time violation is: A changes, the C2 clock goes high after a little less than the setup time, generating a violation. You need to keep the signal stable until the next clock cycle + hold time, or for a total of clock period + setup time + hold time. Since usually setup + hold time < clock period, holding the signal stable for two clock cycles solves the problem.

Comment: but it still does not explain why 'hold time of the first synchronizer flip-flop" ?

Comment: @kevin that doesn’t sound right. It needs to be clock period + setup time + hold time. Draw the timing diagrams or write some simulations to see how it works.